# Google Chrome doesn't show openid-selector

Tags: google-chrome, openid-selector

does anybody have this problem?

I tested my page with IE6, IE7, IE8, FF, Safari, Opera... it works with them, but Chrome just doesn't render it...

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `openid-selector 1.0`. You should upgrade to `openid-selector v1.2`.